# Jasmine TypeError: this.form._updateTreeValidity is not a function

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular-reactive-forms

I have this error on a test of a ReactiveForm Component

I've already seen some other stack posts suggesting that using FormGroup instead of FormBuilder to init the form object in the component constructor is now standard with the new API so I've updated that.

I import ReactiveFormsModule and FormsModule along with all the form related components and the error doesn't seem to be module related.

My TypeScript isn't throwing errors in compile time and Visual Studio Intellisense seems to be able to find all FormGroup functions just fine so why is this happening at runtime?...

```
18 07 2023 12:22:07.947:INFO [Chrome Headless 88.0.4298.0 (Linux x86_64)]: Connected on socket yOswogfg1gCPWytzAAAA with id 99822341
Chrome Headless 88.0.4298.0 (Linux x86_64) DialogPlanExcepcionComponent should create FAILED
    TypeError: this.form._updateTreeValidity is not a function
        at FormGroupDirective._updateDomValue (node_modules/@angular/forms/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/forms.js:5692:1)
        at FormGroupDirective.ngOnChanges (node_modules/@angular/forms/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/forms.js:5530:1)
        at FormGroupDirective.rememberChangeHistoryAndInvokeOnChangesHook (node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:2390:1)
        at callHook (node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:3409:1)
        at callHooks (node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:3375:1)
        at executeInitAndCheckHooks (node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:3327:1)
        at selectIndexInternal (node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:7560:1)
        at ɵɵadvance (node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:7543:1)
        at DialogPlanExcepcionComponent_Template (ng:///DialogPlanExcepcionComponent.js:140:9)
        at executeTemplate (node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:8689:1)
```

The code of the component is this

```
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { Beneficiario } from 'src/app/model/business/benef/beneficiario';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dialog-plan-excepcion',
  templateUrl: './dialog-plan-excepcion.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dialog-plan-excepcion.component.sass']
})
export class DialogPlanExcepcionComponent implements OnInit {

  beneficiario: Beneficiario;
  motivoForm = this.fb.group({
    motivo: ['', Validators.required]
  });
  caso: number;
  enfermedad: string;
  prestacion: string;

  constructor(
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) private data: any,
    private dialog: MatDialogRef<DialogPlanExcepcionComponent>,
    private fb: FormBuilder

  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.beneficiario = this.data['beneficiario'];
    this.caso = this.data['caso'];
    this.enfermedad = this.data['enfermedad'];
    this.prestacion = this.data['prestacion'];
    
  }

  hasRequiredError(formControlName: string): boolean {
    const formControl = this.motivoForm.get(formControlName);
    return formControl.errors?.required && formControl.touched;
  }

  close(flag: string): void {
    console.log("motivo: ",flag)
    if (this.motivoForm.invalid && flag) {
      this.motivoForm.markAllAsTouched();
    } else {
      this.dialog.close(flag);
    }
  }

}
```

The code of the html is this

```
<h1 class="title-dialog" mat-dialog-title>
    Atención
</h1>
<mat-dialog-content id="contente-dialog-check-list" class="content-dialog">
    <!-- 
    <p>El beneficiario {{ beneficiario.fullName }} se encuentra:</p>
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let motivo of motivos">{{ motivo }}</li>
    </ul>
    -->
    <div class="text-exception"  [ngSwitch]="caso">
        <p *ngSwitchCase="'1'">
            La enfermedad <strong>{{enfermedad}}</strong> no se encuentra en el plan del beneficiario <strong>{{beneficiario.fullName}}</strong>.
        </p>
        <p *ngSwitchCase="'2'">
            La prestación <strong>{{prestacion}}</strong> no se encuentra en el plan del beneficiario <strong>{{beneficiario.fullName}}</strong>.
        </p>
        <p *ngSwitchCase="'3'">
            La enfermedad <strong>{{enfermedad}}</strong> y la prestación <strong>{{prestacion}}</strong> no se encuentran en el plan del beneficiario <strong>{{beneficiario.fullName}}</strong>
        </p>
    </div>
    
    <p style="text-align:center">¿Desea exceptuar el requerimiento?</p>
    <form [formGroup]="motivoForm">
        <mat-form-field color="accent" class="w-100">
            <mat-label>Motivo</mat-label>
            <input
            matInput
            id="text_motivo"
            placeholder="Escribir motivo"
            formControlName="motivo"/>
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-error *ngIf="hasRequiredError('motivo')">
             Campo requerido.
        </mat-error>
  </form> 
</mat-dialog-content>
<mat-dialog-actions class="button-actions">
    <button mat-raised-button color="warn" class="w-40" (click)="close('false')">Cancelar</button>
    <button mat-raised-button color="accent" class="w-40" (click)="close(motivoForm.value)">Aceptar</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

An the code of the test is this

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { DialogPlanExcepcionComponent } from './dialog-plan-excepcion.component';
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogModule, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { FormBuilder, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

fdescribe('DialogPlanExcepcionComponent', () => {
  let component: DialogPlanExcepcionComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<DialogPlanExcepcionComponent>;
  let dialogRefSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<MatDialogRef<DialogPlanExcepcionComponent>>;
  const mockData = {
    beneficiario: {
      "aseNumber": "2222",
      "relativeOrd": 0,
      "documentNumber": 222222,
      "cuil": 222222222,
      "fullName": "text",
      "gender": "M",
      "civilState": "C",
      "street": "text",
      "streetNumber": 7,
      "dptFloor": null,
      "zipCode": "1111",
      "region": "xxxxxxxx",
      "lastUpdate": "25/09/2015",
      "lastUpdateTime": "19:39:56",
      "redNumber": 34,
      "companyNumber": 25047,
      "companySucursal": 0,
      "email": "",
      "phoneNumber": "4620-2641",
      "active": true,
      "moroso": true,
      "isMoroso": true,
      "pmo": "N/A",
      "pmoDesc": "N/A",
      "redDescripcion": "xxxxx",
      "categoriaDesc": "xxxx",
      "empresaDescripcion": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
      "fechaNacimiento": null,
      "filialNumber": null,
      "planNumber": null,
      "companyDescription": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  },
    caso: 1,
    enfermedad: 'Enfermedad',
    prestacion: 'Prestacion',
  };

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const formBuilderStub = () => ({
      group: () => ({
        motivo: ['', Validators.required]
      })
    });

    const matDialogRefSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('MatDialogRef', ['close']);
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [MatDialogModule,ReactiveFormsModule,FormsModule],
      declarations: [ DialogPlanExcepcionComponent ],
      providers:[
        { provide: FormBuilder, useFactory: formBuilderStub },
        { provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: mockData },
        { provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: matDialogRefSpy }
      ],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DialogPlanExcepcionComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

});
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing this line:

```
{ provide: FormBuilder, useFactory: formBuilderStub },
```

in the `providers` array of `TestBed.configureTestingModule({`.

That line is basically saying when you want to use `FormBuilder`, use `formBuilderStub` instead. I think having `ReactiveFormsModule` in the `imports` array should be enough.